# Backbone fetch collection + Rails

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, backbone.js, coffeescript

js files:

```
class BackApp.Collections.Posts extends Backbone.Collection
  url: '/api/posts'
  model: BackApp.Models.Post

class BackApp.Models.Post extends Backbone.Model

class BackApp.Routers.Posts extends Backbone.Router
  routes:
    '': 'index'
  initialize: ->
    @collection = new BackApp.Collections.Posts
    @collection.fetch()
  index: ->
    #view = new BackApp.Views.PostsIndex(collection: @collection)
    #$("#container").html(view.render().el)
```

rails routes:

```
  scope "api" do
    resources :posts
  end
  root :to => 'main#index'
```

So , when i am trying fetch collection in chrome console like :

```
collection = new BackApp.Collections.Posts
collection.fetch()
collection.length # => 3
```

But if i wrote it (console.log) in posts routes file in initialize function it show 0
Why?

Comment: dont forget up me. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@collection.fetch() executes async.

When you try chrome console data already loaded when you use console.log(), but when you try it with js code data is to loaded yet when you use console.log()

You should use success callback to know length of collection when it loaded:

```
@collection.fetch(
  success: (collection, response, options) ->
    console.log collection.models.length
)
```

Comment: thanks a lot!! I tried this variant, but i forgot about arguments to success callback, so, now it works:)